# "Transitive type conversion" in typescript

Tags: typescript

in a typescript project which I'm currently working on, I have a `class A`, a `class B extends A`, a `class C extends B` and a `class D extends C`. I also have a method `getFoo(): A`.

The following type conversion doesn't work:

`const foo = this.getFoo() as D;`

The error I get is that the conversion may be a mistake, because neither type sufficiently overlaps the other (although D is a subclass of A).

What, funnily enough, works, is:

`const foo = this.getFoo() as C as D`

Why? Is the inheritance chain somehow too long for TS? Is there any way to write this without the double cast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share reproducible example

Comment: what class is the `this` object? could you please reproduce in typescript playground?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behavior you're describing, but this code worked fine: https://tsplay.dev/WkMajN. What version of TypeScript are you using? And in your example when you say `this.getFoo()`, what does `this` refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the question eventually.

My initial description was too simplified. In reality, it was like this:

- Classes `A` and `B` were defined inside a type declaration library `lorem`, each as a default export from its own module. Class `B` extends `A`.
- Classes `C`, better called `my/B`, and `D` were declared inside my own `my.d.ts` file. Class `C` actually had the same name as class `B`, so I had to rename it during import.
- All of this was used inside my own class `E`, which had a method `getFoo(): A`.

What I initially wrote was (`my.d.ts`)

```
declare module "my/B" {
  import {B as LoremB} from "lorem/B";

  export default class B extends LoremB {
  }
}

declare module "my/D" {
  import B from "my/B";

  export default class D extends B {
    public doSomething(): void
  }
}
```

and (`E.ts`)

```
(this.getFoo() as D).doSomething();
```

This gave me the error message that the conversion may be a mistake because neither `A` or `D` sufficiently overlap each other and that `doSomething` is missing from `A`.

It turns out the import of `lorem/B` should be written as `import LoremB from "lorem/B"` instead. Typescript did not complain because of this, I guess because of `"skipLibCheck": true`? But writing the import as `import LoremB from "lorem/B"` solved the problem.